# removeClass() and addClass() Casing Strange Behaviour in Safari

Tags: jquery, css

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/cSPBf/

**Background**
I have a page which demonstrates a number of different list types using CSS.  When a visitor to the page clicks on a button, a sample list has all of its classes removed (i.e., removeClass()) and then has the specific class which corresponds to the clicked button added to it (i.e., addClass()).  This setup, obviously, uses jQuery.

**Issue**
Everything works as intended in Chrome and Firefox (I have not yet tested IE), but Safari has trouble with about a third of my list styles.  Please see the jsfiddle link for the problematic code sections.  Significantly, the issue crops up only when switching back and forth between multiple styles (and not even for all the styles).  An issue with the counter() seems to arise where the numbering is either off (e.g., the first li receives a 0) or completely non-functional (i.e., all li's receive a 0).  Notably, the issue does not present when the "reset formatting" button (which simply performs a removeClass() on the sample text) is pressed in between formatting style buttons.  This is all the more odd as each of the buttons includes a removeClass() directive before the pertinent addClass() directive.

**More Information**
As you can see from the jsfiddle, I am using :before and content to add the list numbering to the example text.  Safari has no trouble with any of the list styles which do not have anything before counter().  The issue arises when there is something located before counter() (e.g., '\28').  I'm uncertain of what is causing this strange behaviour.

**Troubleshooting Thus Far**
I have rearranged the elements of the content styling and the issue seems to present only when counter() has something preceding it.  Changing the spacing in the content directive has no effect.  The jQuery which removes and then adds classes reacts precisely the same if the two directives are on one line or two; further, adding a delay did nothing.

**A bit of code**
*CSS Sample*

```
.zlist-upper-roman-parens ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: zlist-upper-roman-parens;
}

.zlist-upper-roman-parens ol li:before {
    content: '\28'counter(zlist-upper-roman-parens, upper-roman)'\29';
    counter-increment: zlist-upper-roman-parens;
}
```

*jQuery Sample*

```
$("#zlist-upper-roman-parens").click(function () {
    $("#zlist-example-displayer2").removeClass()
    $("#zlist-example-displayer2").addClass("zlist-upper-roman-parens");
});
```

Comment: Make sure each command  is terminated correctly (e.g. `$("#zlist-example-displayer2").removeClass();`) and try chaining commands (e.g. `$("#zlist-example-displayer2").removeClass().addClass("zlist-upper-roman-parens");`). I don't have Safari so can't debug this

Comment: Chaining the commands was one of the first things I tried, but that didn't have any effect on the issue, unfortunately.  I've also tried with and without the terminating ";" and it, also, seems to have no effect.